# IF & ELSE FOR FLUTTER | WORKING PRINCIPLE OF FLUTTER & DART

Tags: flutter, dart

I just started learning to code with Flutter & Dart. I could not fully understand the working principle of Flutter. There are no errors on the code I shared below. But I am not getting the result I want. On the code, the counter starts from 0. And there is a text on the counter that shows whether this counter is even or odd. This is done when the button is clicked. But the button only works once. The counter increases but the text does not change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String evenNumber = "Even Number";
  String oddNumber = "Odd Number";

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(_counter / 2 == 0 ? evenNumber : oddNumber),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is also the `isEven` property of `int` https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/int/isEven.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
_counter / 2 == 0 ? evenNumber : oddNumber
```

To:

```
_counter % 2 == 0 ? evenNumber : oddNumber
```

The '%' operator evaluates the remainder that you need. Not the half (_counter/2) of counter value.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get your desired result because you are using using the normal `division` instead of `modulo`. With `/` you only check if the result is `0` and with `%` you can check if the number is even. To fix this change your `Text` widget to the following.

```
Text(_counter % 2 == 0 ? evenNumber : oddNumber),
```

Your full code should look like this now.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String evenNumber = "Even Number";
  String oddNumber = "Odd Number";

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(_counter / 2 == 0 ? evenNumber : oddNumber),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```